# Custom symbols in curl get variable fail the request to an api

Tags: php, non-ascii-characters

I have an API which is called by name and returns the players ID, the name can have custom characters when I do the request like this:

```
$url = 'http://eune.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.4/summoner/by-name/'.( $name ).'?api_key=';
$getSummoner = file_get_contents($url);
```

With name value for example:

```
$name = "Viliś";
```

I get an error becouse of this letter: `ś` or similar.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) , I guess

Comment: then this happens
Problem accessing /api/lol/eune/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Vili%EF%BF%BD. Reason: <pre> Not Found</pre>